# 3-way circuit to 4-way?

Tags: electrical

I have two parallel stairways with a light & 3-way switch at the top of each. How can I add switches at the bottom of each stairway to control the lights along with the 3-switches at the top of the stairways?

Comment: it is unclear how many lights you have, how everything works now and how you want it to work ......... please draw a diagram

Comment: So do you want 2 additional switches to control each stairway light separately, or 1 additional switch that controls both stairway lights together?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want four switches in total, but you only have two now? I am not sure how your parallel stairways are configured exactly and how lighting in one would affect the other. It does seem unusual. N.B. Those 4-way switches aren't cheap, about $40 each. There may be a better way to solve this altogether, like two seperate 3-way switches, independant of each other, one pair for each stairway?

Comment: I typically pay $12 in the US.

Comment: Wow. I'm in Canada. They're about $35. here, plus tax, at HD.